# Foundation reveal modal not binding the property with Angular2 component

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, angular2-template, angular2-services

In my application, I have a foundation reveal, which gets called from a button of the html template of a component and show data in textboxes. It is working fine when I load the application. Once I go to another tab and comes back then my page loads the data correctly but reveal modal not able to bind to properties of component and no data displayed.

I am doing `jQuery(document).foundation()` in `ngviewAfterInit()` in each component.
If I do `{{component field}}`, it prints it in the modal but``
`<input name="abc" type="text" ([ngModel]) ="component field" >`
not showing the value

Please note: Issue comes when I revisit the page. On first go it works but once I switch to another page, (another component based) and comes back to original page then I face the above issue(Also issue is only with Modal not with the original page).

Comment: ohhh, apology for that, I will take care of this in future

Comment: Guys did anyone find a solution to this . Foundation is just not working with angular on the modals and on the net is all about angular and bootstrap.